# Is it possible to create your own Convolution Neural Network(CNN) by hand(without using any frameworks like Keras, Caffe, TF)?

Tags: python, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I want to create your own simple CNN, but I need in some ready implementations.
Can your share me links, articles, where I can find ready implementations of CNN(without using any frameworks Keras, but maybe with numpy,scipy)where I can see the implementation of each operations, like matrices multiplication and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to implement your own bare-bones CNN without help of any frameworks like Keras, TF, etc. You can check out this [simple implementation of CNNs](http://www.imm.dtu.dk/~abll/blog/simple_cnn/) using numpy/cython and the code repository [here](https://github.com/andersbll/nnet).

Comment: Thanks, i was looking for this. I'd be glad to get any more links

Comment: I'm wotking on an inference only framework but you can also refernce it for forward proppgration. https://github.com/danFromTelAviv/cynfrence